# What distribution has these properties?

Tags: probability-distributions

There is a 2D continuous distribution from an actual physical process which I want to model mathematically. I have 40k samples. You can see a histogram [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D7hc.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G841b.png).

---

This can be summarized as 4 properties, listed in order of prevalence. Further down the list needs more samples to be apparent. I use $f(x,y)$ to denote the probability density function.

1. It is symmetric: $f(x,y)=f(-x,y)=f(y,x)$
2. It is centered on $(0,0)$: $|(x_1,y_1)|<|(x_2,y_2)|\implies f(x_1,y_1)>f(x_2,y_2)$
3. Near the axes is more likely
4. Near the diagonals is slightly more likely

I can't come up with a clean mathematical description for axes/diagonal, but in words, for a fixed $|(x,y)|$, the global maximum $A_1=f(x,y)$ is where $x=0$ or $y=0$, there is a local maximum $A_2$ where $x=y$ or $x=-y$, and compared to the global minimum $B$, $A_2-B$ is much less than $A_1-B$.

Properties #1 and #2 are immediately obvious, and #3 shows up with a small number of samples. The diagonals being more likely is only barely visible with 40k samples. I don't think other lines will be more probable, since the axes and diagonals are the special ones. If it does follow a half angle subdividing pattern or something, I'd think each $A_i-B$ will be exponentially smaller.

Since this is modelling a physical process, there is a bound, but it is high enough to not matter. We can assume it's unbounded.

So, **what distribution has these properties?**

---

Someone might say *if it's a physical process, why not analyze that to find the distribution?* That would require understanding the physical process, and it's too complicated for that. It's hard to even know all the variables. The result is a 2D point for each measurement, and that's easy to analyze. It is indeed only an approximation, but in practice an accurate approximation is good enough.

---

It is possible that the diagonals is just a fluke since the difference is so small. Perhaps the histogram bins were biased in a way that made diagonals look slightly more probable. Or the measurements had too large of a granularity. I'll have to go back and collect more samples to confirm.